# count no of clicks on a button in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form control button which i want to use to group-ungroup columns.That is if it is clicked the first time it groups/hides those columns and next time it it clicked it unhides those columns.

I want to count the no of click on that button so that ,if the `variable` containing the `no of clicks` count is `odd` i will hide the columns else if it is `even` i will unhide the column.

this is my code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Static cnt As Long
cnt = 0
Dim remain As Integer
cnt = cnt + 1


remain = cnt Mod 2

If remain = 1 Then
 ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
 End If

 If remain = 2 Then
 ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=2
 End If


End Sub
```

So how can i count the no of clicks on that button  in a variable in vba.
Sorry for the bad english?

Comment: I can give you the answer but please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: i have edited the post and given my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok you do not need to use a count and keep adding to it. You can use a `Boolean` Variable instead. Here is an example. This works an an `ON/OFF` switch.

```
Option Explicit

Dim boolOn As Boolean

Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If boolOn = False Then
        boolOn = True

        MsgBox "OFF"
        '
        '~~> Do what you want to do
        '
    Else
        boolOn = False
        '
        '~~> Do what you want to do
        '
        MsgBox "ON"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If boolOn = False Then
        boolOn = True

        ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
        
    Else
        boolOn = False
       
        ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=2
    End If
End Sub`
   
This is the code i modified but this is not giving the desired effect i want

Comment: Please explain "Desired effect"

Comment: sorry I rectified my mistake.Thanks a lot for the solution