# Macro/Private Sub: Set similar filter on several sheets simultaneously

Tags: excel, vba

I work with sheets named; Rev00, Rev01, Rev02 etc - among other sheets in my workbook.

It would be very helpful (in order to compare the sub-summaries of different revisions) to set the exact same multiple-filter - as set in active sheet - in only all sheets beginning with "Rev".

This action should most wanted be activated by double Click in `Range("A1")` or somewhere like that (I dont want button on this one).

If possible next double Click in Range("A1") should reset filters.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, str As String        
    For Each ws In Worksheets            
            str = Left(ws.Name, 3)                    
                If str = "Rev" Then                        
                    ' set filter as in active.sheet                    
                End If
     Next ws
End Sub
```

... and I am stuck ....
will anyone guide me on this?

Comment: what is your actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. :) Here is a basic sample on how it should work.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, str As String

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        str = Left(ws.Name, 3)
        If UCase(str) = "REV" Then
            With ws
                '~~> Remove any filters
                .AutoFilterMode = False

                With <YOUR RANGE>
                    .AutoFilter Field:=<RELEVANT FIELD>, _
                                Criteria1:=<YOUR CRITERIA>

                    '
                    '~~> Rest of the code
                    '
                End With

                '~~> Remove any filters
                '.AutoFilterMode = False
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s) you can see Autofilter in action :)

To call the above code by clicking Range `A1`, you can use the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        '
        '~~> Your code goes here
        '
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Regarding your query about making Range `A1` respond as an ON/OFF switch, you can use a boolean variable s shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272202/count-no-of-clicks-on-a-button-in-excel-vba)

Comment: I really dint get the criteria1

Comment: Did you see the link below that piece of code on how to define your citeria1?

Comment: I set a multipel filter in active sheet Revxx, then activate the macro that sets the exact same multipel filter in the rest of Rev's

Comment: What code are you using to set the filter in revx sheet? use that same `.Autofilter` line in place of `.AutoFilter Field:=<RELEVANT FIELD>, _
                                Criteria1:=<YOUR CRITERIA>`

Comment: relevant criterias can be elected from any range in A1:AL1

Comment: I use plain Excel filter (not macro based) in active sheet and want the macro to "read" all used parameters and set the very same filter in all other Rev's

Comment: Ah I see :) In that case, see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489126/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-save-restore-a-user-defined-filter)